# Why are my images not in order while using ng-repeat orderBy?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to get images from a database, and then show them in order or their ids ascending.

In my controller, I have `this.imageListFromDatabase = images.data.images;`
which is an array of 24 objects. Each object is of the type

```
$$hashKey:"object:259"
batchId:"1470168280191"
createdAt:"2016-08-02T20:04:40.463Z"
dimensionUnits:"px"
displayName:"2008_005867.jpg"
fileName:"2f87c5ab8d7e7d02dd068a0df8ebf14c.jpg"
fileSize:"162941"
id:200
md5Hash:"2f87c5ab8d7e7d02dd068a0df8ebf14c"
rawHeight:"333"
rawWidth:"500"
updatedAt:"2016-08-02T20:04:40.463Z"
```

In my template, I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="imageContainer" ng-repeat="img in vm.imageListFromDatabase | orderBy:'id'">
    <img class="imageListImage"
    ui-sref="image({id: img.id})"
    ng-src="{{[vm.storageLocation, img.fileName].join('')}}">
</div>
```

Can you tell me how I can order the images by id, and why this is not working the way it should?

Comment: Could u upload a snippet?

Comment: `not working the way it should`: what should it do, and what does it do instead? Post a concrete example.